# How to add tri state checkboxes to treeview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I need to have a treeview control in asp.net with tri state checkboxes using c#. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you want users to be able to select multiple nodes, you can use the TreeView control to display a check box next to a node image. When the ShowCheckBoxes property is set to a TreeNodeType other than TreeNodeType.None, check boxes are displayed next to the specified nodes. When check boxes are displayed, you can use the TreeNodeCheckChanged event to run your custom routine whenever the state of a check box changes between posts to the server. The next time the page is posted to the server, the CheckedNodes property is populated with the selected nodes.

Comment: But would this give me tri state checkboxes?

Comment: http://myworkcodes.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/getting-all-checked-checkboxes-from-treeview-in-asp-net-using-c/

Answer (score 1):

You can use either for the codes with can help you

[CodeProject:1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6549/Tri-State-TreeView-Control)

[CodeProject:2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59514/Simple-Tri-State-TreeView)

[CodeProject:3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34751/Three-State-Treeview-Part-2)

[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002/how-do-i-create-tri-state-checkboxes-with-a-treeview-control-in-net)

IF anything let me know.